# awk adds carriage return when used in script versus commandline

Tags: awk

**From command line:**

```
$cat file.txt

OLAPSYS:3FB8EF9DB538647C:LOCKED OR EXPIRED
```

**Run awk on file.txt:**

```
awk  '{sub(/[  ]+/," ")}1'   file.txt
```

Expected result:   `OLAPSYS:3FB8EF9DB538647C:LOCKED OR EXPIRED`

**From My Script:** $cat script.sh

```
active_db_users="OLAPSYS:3FB8EF9DB538647C:LOCKED OR EXPIRED"

for i in $active_db_users

do

    acct_status=$(echo $i | awk '{sub(/[  ]+/," ")}1')
    echo $acct_status
done
```

**Run the Script:**

```
./script.sh > output

cat output

OLAPSYS:3FB8EF9DB538647C:LOCKED

OR

EXPIRED
```

**Unexpected Result has carriage return. How do I modify the script so the result is one line with no carriage return:**

**OLAPSYS:3FB8EF9DB538647C:LOCKED OR EXPIRED**

Comment: How many iterations of the loop are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Quote your shell variables properly:

```
active_db_users="OLAPSYS:3FB8EF9DB538647C:LOCKED OR EXPIRED"

for i in "$active_db_users"
do
    acct_status="$(echo "$i" | awk '{sub(/[  ]+/," ")}1')"
    echo "$acct_status"
done
```

then run the script again and let us know if you still have a problem.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/133219 if you don't know why you should always quote your variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by leaving them unquoted and fully understand all the implications.

Also read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice - whatever it is you're trying to do the above script seems like the wrong approach.